# How to get and use the expected API response type in a Moshi adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

Below are some simplified samples of json responses I am getting from a collection of related endpoints. There are about 15 different calls/variations of the successful json response. The error json response comes back in the same format as success (with a 200 status), but it has a status of "error" with the error message in the data property, which otherwise, on success, would contain the expected result.

Success samples:

`{"status":"ok","data":{"favourites":[{"name":"story A", "id":"123"},{"name":"story B", "id":"321"}]}}`

`{"status":"ok","data":{"name":"boris","age":"23"}}`

Error sample:

`{"status":"error","data":"Error message here"}`

I know i can create an adapter for each API call with a success and fail variation based on status, with a suitable data type to suit. Or similarly for example using polymorphic:

```
PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(FavouritesResponse::class.java, "status")
                        .withSubtype(FavouritesResponse::class.java, Status.ok.name)
                        .withSubtype(FavouritesFailResponse::class.java, Status.error.name)
```

But using this approach i'd need one of these for each of my API calls, which seems overkill. It would seem to make sense that I could create a type Adapter capable of returning a new model type with nullable data and error properties, that can handle all my variations.

So my models would look like:

```
class OriginalFormat<T> {
    var status: String? = null
    var data: T? = null
}

class ProcessedFormat<T> {
    var status: String? = null
    var data: T? = null
    var error: String? = null
}
```

and my adapter would do something along the lines of the following (my understanding of handling generic types falls over here):

```
    @FromJson
    fun eventFromJson(incoming: OriginalFormat<T>): ProcessedFormat<T> {
        val processed = ProcessedFormat<T::class.java>()
        processed.status = incoming.status
        if(processed.status == "ok"){
            processed.error = null
            processed.data = incoming.data
        } else {
            processed.error = incoming.data
            processed.data = null
        }
        return processed
    }
```

My API interface might then look like:

```
    @GET("person")
    suspend fun getPerson(
        @Query("id") id: Int,
    ): ProcessedFormat<Person>

    @GET("favourites")
    suspend fun getFavourites(
        @Query("id") id: Int,
    ): ProcessedFormat<Favourites>
```

Simply put could this work? If so any pointers welcome. Or am I missing a simpler resolution?

Thanks -
Mathew